# Xmlstarlet command from terminal to Windows Powershell

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, cmd, xmlstarlet

On my terminal (linux/mac) I use this:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N ns=http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1 -d //ns:div[not(contains(@xml:lang,'Italian'))] "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml" > "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml.conv"
```

On windows (powershell) I really don't know how to fix this command. I know that I need to use $ instead of @ (because the powershell said to use $ instead of @), but there is something wrong with contains:

```
./xml.exe ed -N ns=http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1 -d //ns:div[not(contains($xml:lang,'Italian'))] "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml" > "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml.conv"
```

I even tried this:

```
./xml.exe ed -N ns=http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1 -d //ns:div[not($xml:lang -contains'Italian')] "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml" > "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml.conv"
```

But I get "failed to load external entity "False""

Comment: What does "on my terminal" mean? A non-Windows kind of terminal? What shell? Does "on Windows" mean in a cmd.exe shell or powershell? "I know that I need to use $ instead of @" - Why do you think that?

Comment: by terminal I mean linux/mac. On windows I use powershell. I know that I need $ instead of @ because powershell told me to do that.. I edited my main question.

Comment: I get ``bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`` when running your initial command in a bash shell. Shouldn't you have quotes around the `//ns:div...`?

Comment: I will try it as soon as possible.I copied it from a Java script so it's possible.

Comment: You are right, on bash I use "//ns:div[not(contains(@xml:lang,'Italian'))]" something like that with " "

Comment: Ok thank you. That's was the problem. Maybe you can copy your answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`//ns:div[not(contains(@xml:lang,'Italian'))]` is an XPath expression which contains some characters that are special to various shells, therefore you should protect it with quotes.  Using double quotes works in bash, Powershell, and cmd.exe:

```
xmlstarlet ed -N ns=http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1 -d "//ns:div[not(contains(@xml:lang,'Italian'))]" "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml" > "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml.conv"
```

When using bash or Powershell it may be preferable to use single quotes; for those shells this is needed to protect against expansion of `$` (although use of this in XPath is fairly advanced):

```
xmlstarlet ed -N ns=http://www.w3.org/2006/04/ttaf1 -d '//ns:div[not(contains(@xml:lang,"Italian"))]' "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml" > "C:\Users\1H144708H\Downloads\a.mul.ttml.conv"
```

Note that the inner quotes need to swapped as well.